# Correct way to extend classes with Symfony autowiring

Tags: php, symfony

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to extend and use classes with Symfonies autowiring.

For example, I have a BaseClass that instantiates and auto wires the entity manager.

```
class BaseClass
{
  protected $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  protected function someMethodIWantToUse(Entity $something)
  {
    // Do something there
    $this->entityManager->persist($something);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
  }
}
```

Then I have a subclass that extends the BaseClass and needs access that method. So I let it autowire again and pass it to the parent constructor.

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
  private $handler;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, SomeHandler $handler)
  {
    parent::__construct($em);
    $this->handler = $handler;
  }

  public function SubClassMethod()
  {
    // Get some data or do something
    $entity = SomeEntityIGot();
    $this->someMethodIWantToUse($entity);
  }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if this is actually the correct way to do this or there's something I'm missing and the parent class should be able to autowire the entitymanager by itself?

Comment: It's not a Symfony thing, it's a OOP PHP thing.

Comment: It actually is a Symfony autowire thing and you are doing it correctly.  If you did not need to inject an additional argument ($handler) then you would not need a constructor at all for SubClass.  Sometimes you might see setter injection being used for common base dependencies thus eliminating the base constructor.  This makes it a bit easier to extend the class.  But there is no need for that for your use case.

Comment: it's also an oop thing too. depending on what the sub-class does, and if it really *is* a subclass, (semantically, that is) the decorator pattern *might* be more appropriate.

Comment: Thnx all. So I think the question has been answered for me. 1) Yes, it is the correct way. 2) I need to get a better understanding of design patterns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To summarize the comments, yes your way is correct. Depending on your use case there are alternatives.

This are the ways you can go about it:

**1. Extending Class and using [Constructor Injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection) (what you do)**

```
    class BaseClass {
        protected $some;

        public function __construct(SomeInterface $some)
        {
            $this->some = $some;
        }
    }

    class SubClass extends BaseClass {
        private $other;

        public function __construct(SomeInterface $some, OtherInterface $other)
        {
            parent::__construct($some);
            $this->other = $other;
        }
    }
```

---

**2. [Setter Injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html)**

```
    class BaseClass {
        protected $some;

        public function __construct(SomeInterface $some)
        {
            $this->some = $some;
        }
    }

    class SubClass extends BaseClass {
        private $other;

        public function setOther(OtherInterface $other)
        {
            $this->other = $other;
        }
    }
```

Now `setOther` won't automatically be called, you have to "manually" call it by either specifying a `calls` property in your `services.yaml` file, as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html. This would then look something like this:

```
// services.yaml
App\SubClass:
    calls:
        - [setOther, ['@other']]
```

Or

```
// services.yaml
app.sub_class:
    class: App\SubClass
    calls:
        - [setOther, ['@other']]
```

assuming, an implementation of `OtherInterface` is available as `@other` in the service container.

A more elegant solution if you're using autowiring, simply add a `@required` annotation to the function as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-calls, which would look like this:

```
/**
 * @required
 */
public function setOther(OtherInterface $other)
{
    $this->other = $other;
}
```

---

**3. [Property Injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#property-injection)**

```
    class BaseClass {
        protected $some;

        public function __construct(SomeInterface $some)
        {
            $this->some = $some;
        }
    }

    class SubClass extends BaseClass {
        public $other;
    }
```

As with the Setter Injection, you'll need to tell Symfony to populate this property, by specifying it in your `services.yaml` file like this:

```
// services.yaml
App\SubClass:
    properties:
        other: '@other'
```

Or

```
// services.yaml
app.sub_class:
    class: App\SubClass
    properties:
        other: '@other'
```

assuming, an implementation of `OtherInterface` is available as `@other` in the service container.

---

**Conclusion:**
Since there are different ways to solve this, it's up to you to determine the correct way for your use case. I personally go with either option 1 (Constructor Injection) or option 2 (Setter Injection) using the annotation. Both of them allow you to use typehints and thus allowing your IDE to help you write clean code.
In 90% of cases, I'd go with option 1, as then it's clear for every one reading your code, what services are available with one glance at the `__constructor` function.
One use case for Setter Injection would be a base class offering all the `setXXX` functions but then sub classes not needing all of them. You could have a constructor in each sub class, requesting the needed services and then calling the `setXXX` methods of the base class.
*Note: this is kind of an edge case and you probably won't run into this.*

You can find a list of advantages and disadvantages of each method directly in the Symfony documentation about the [Service Container -> Types of Injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#property-injection)

Comment: As of Php 8, we can also use `Symfony\Contracts\Service\Attribute\Required` instead of `@required` annotation. Regarding second approach of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This way too :

```
class BaseClass
{
   protected Environment $twig;

   #[Required]
   public function setTwig(Environment $twig): void
   { $this->twig = $twig; }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function __construct(
       private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    ) { }

    public function test()
    {
       $this->twig->render(......);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).